# Mobile navigation jQuery jumping, and navigation disappears when re-sized?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mobile, responsive-design

The navigation in the site below is not functioning properly. For some reason when the mobile navigation is activated, the li of the navigation jump into place, rather than settling where they are. I'm unable to locate the problem stylings (I assume it's a css based issue).

Also, when in the mobile view, opening the navigation, then closing it and re-sizing the browser, the navigation is still hidden! Is there a way to clear the cache so the navigation no longer uses the hidden declaration?

Thanks!

http://wheelingforward.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could reproduce the issue by resizing the browser and noticed that something is adding an inline style declaration to the nav element (display:none). So when the browser is resized back to a wider screen it's hard to override that inline style.

So, I would suggest not to add this inline style. Instead use media queries or if you're using a javascript framework such as jQuery use the hide, show or toggle functions.

Hope the info here leads you to the solution you are looking for

Leo